# Extending my application - Pyramid/Pylons/Python

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

Simple question about extending my application

Lets say I have a "Main Application", and in this application I have the following in the _init_.py file:

```
config.add_route('image_upload', '/admin/image_upload/', 
    view='mainapp.views.uploader',
    view_renderer='/site/upload.mako')
```

and in the views.py I have:

```
def uploader(request):
    # some code goes here
    return {'xyz':xyz}
```

Now when I create a new application, and I want to extend it, to use the above view and route:

In the new application _init_.py  file I would manually copy over the config.add_route code:

```
config.add_route( 'image_upload', '/admin/image_upload/', 
   view='mainapp.views.uploader', 
   view_renderer='mainapp:templates/site/upload.mako'
 )
```

And is that all I would need to do? From this would my application be able to use the view and template from the main application, or is am I missing something else?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to copy your code to do this. Use the [Configurator.include](https://pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/api/config.html) method to include your "Main Application" configuration in your new application. The documentation explains this pretty well both [here](https://pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/narr/advconfig.html?highlight=extending#including-configuration-from-external-sources) and [here](https://pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/api/config.html), but the essentially, if you declare your main apps configuration inside a callable:

```
def main_app_config(config):

    config.add_route('image_upload', '/admin/image_upload/', 
    view='mainapp.views.uploader',
    view_renderer='/site/upload.mako')
```

Then you can include your main app in your new app's configuration like this:

```
from my.main.app import main_app_config

# do your new application Configurator setup, etc.
# then "include" it.

config.include(main_app_config)

# continue on with your new app configuration
```

Comment: Would you know how to resolve the following error: `UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|projects|projects, SQL expression or this Session` the view is making a query to a table (also I want it to use the DB in the new application and not the one in the original application.)

Comment: @sidewinder From the error it sounds as if you have not created the sqla engine for your main apps database. You can configure SqlAlchemy to manage separate engines, etc., or what I've in the past is just use the main app's sqla configuration and extend it in my new app. It really depends on how your apps integrate with one another. The best thing would be to create a new question where you can outline your problem in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. The SQLA config seems to be okay from both sides. What has worked for me though is by changing this in the new application __init__.py file: `from mainapp.models import initialize_sql` so I am importing the initialize_sql from the main application. Is this how you have done it in your previous applications as well, I'd be interested to know.